# Error "Invalid X509 ASN.1 file" in libCurl with axTLS

Tags: c, ssl, curl, embedded

I am using libCurl with axTLS (http://sourceforge.net/projects/axtls/files/1.5.3/ ) in an embedded project.

when compiling the axTLS I used the following configuration for SSL:

```
#
# SSL Library
#
# CONFIG_SSL_SERVER_ONLY is not set
# CONFIG_SSL_CERT_VERIFICATION is not set
# CONFIG_SSL_ENABLE_CLIENT is not set
CONFIG_SSL_FULL_MODE=y
# CONFIG_SSL_SKELETON_MODE is not set
# CONFIG_SSL_PROT_LOW is not set
CONFIG_SSL_PROT_MEDIUM=y
# CONFIG_SSL_PROT_HIGH is not set
CONFIG_SSL_USE_DEFAULT_KEY=y
CONFIG_SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_LOCATION=""
CONFIG_SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD=""
CONFIG_SSL_X509_CERT_LOCATION=""
# CONFIG_SSL_GENERATE_X509_CERT is not set
CONFIG_SSL_X509_COMMON_NAME=""
CONFIG_SSL_X509_ORGANIZATION_NAME=""
CONFIG_SSL_X509_ORGANIZATION_UNIT_NAME=""
CONFIG_SSL_ENABLE_V23_HANDSHAKE=y
CONFIG_SSL_HAS_PEM=y
CONFIG_SSL_USE_PKCS12=y
CONFIG_SSL_EXPIRY_TIME=""
CONFIG_X509_MAX_CA_CERTS=""
CONFIG_SSL_MAX_CERTS=3
CONFIG_SSL_CTX_MUTEXING=y
CONFIG_USE_DEV_URANDOM=y
# CONFIG_WIN32_USE_CRYPTO_LIB is not set
CONFIG_OPENSSL_COMPATIBLE=y
# CONFIG_PERFORMANCE_TESTING is not set
# CONFIG_SSL_TEST is not set
CONFIG_AXTLSWRAP=y
CONFIG_AXHTTPD=y
```

And when I tried to download files using HTTPS I received the following errors:

```
invalid digest: 2a 86 48 ce 3d 04 03 03 
Error: Invalid X509 ASN.1 file (Unsupported digest)
invalid digest: 2a 86 48 ce 3d 04 03 03 
Error: Invalid X509 ASN.1 file (Unsupported digest)
invalid digest: 2a 86 48 ce 3d 04 03 03 
Error: Invalid X509 ASN.1 file (Unsupported digest)
invalid digest: 2a 86 48 ce 3d 04 03 03 
Error: Invalid X509 ASN.1 file (Unsupported digest)
invalid digest: 2a 86 48 ce 3d 04 03 03 
Error: Invalid X509 ASN.1 file (Unsupported digest)
invalid digest: 2a 86 48 ce 3d 04 03 03 
Error: Invalid X509 ASN.1 file (Unsupported digest)
invalid digest: 2a 86 48 ce 3d 04 03 03 
Error: Invalid X509 ASN.1 file (Unsupported digest)
Error: maximum number of CA certs added (150) - change of compile-time configuration required
Error: maximum number of CA certs added (150) - change of compile-time configuration required
Error: maximum number of CA certs added (150) - change of compile-time configuration required
Error: maximum number of CA certs added (150) - change of compile-time configuration required
Error: maximum number of CA certs added (150) - change of compile-time configuration required
Error: maximum number of CA certs added (150) - change of compile-time configuration required
Error: maximum number of CA certs added (150) - change of compile-time configuration required
Error: maximum number of CA certs added (150) - change of compile-time configuration required
Error: maximum number of CA certs added (150) - change of compile-time configuration required
Error: maximum number of CA certs added (150) - change of compile-time configuration required
Error: maximum number of CA certs added (150) - change of compile-time configuration required
Error: maximum number of CA certs added (150) - change of compile-time configuration required
Error: maximum number of CA certs added (150) - change of compile-time configuration required
Error: maximum number of CA certs added (150) - change of compile-time configuration required
Error: maximum number of CA certs added (150) - change of compile-time configuration required
Error: maximum number of CA certs added (150) - change of compile-time configuration required
```

And to initialize Curl's options i used the following code:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, MyURL);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, MyLocalFile);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MyAgent");
curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
```

It's non-blocking error, but my soft take long time to begin downloading. But when i make CONFIG_SSL_GENERATE_X509_CERT=y the error become blocking.
So  how can i fix this error?

Best regards,

Comment: The messages are very clear.

Comment: So Can you guide me towards the solution please?

Comment: Change CONFIG_X509_MAX_CA_CERTS and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Changing CONFIG_X509_MAX_CA_CERTS="" in your code to something larger than 150?  That seems to be what the error is indicating.  If you know how many CA certs you have, you can set it to a higher number than that.